# Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

Tags: npm

I am trying to clone and use pix/pix in my laptop for a university project 
(https://github.com/1024pix/pix). But I am getting the following error:

```
H:\Bachelor YGREC - Modelling & Data Science\Bachelor Year 1\Project\Project 2\pix>npm run configure

> pix@2.116.0 configure H:\Bachelor YGREC - Modelling & Data Science\Bachelor Year 1\Project\Project 2\pix
> npm install && run-s ci:all test configure:api


> pix@2.116.0 preinstall H:\Bachelor YGREC - Modelling & Data Science\Bachelor Year 1\Project\Project 2\pix
> test "$(npm --version)" = 6.13.4

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pix@2.116.0 preinstall: `test "$(npm --version)" = 6.13.4`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pix@2.116.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-24T10_36_42_126Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pix@2.116.0 configure: `npm install && run-s ci:all test configure:api`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pix@2.116.0 configure script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-24T10_36_42_183Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have found the answer by now but if someone else find it useful, just run `npm install` in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Write `npm start` in the terminal followed by `npm install`. This will solve your issue.